# Will socket connection stay open after php script execution completed?

Tags: php, sockets

If we open a socket connection in a php script and don't close it in coding.
After script execution is completed, will the socket connection stay open?

If we open the same script in new tab or refresh the page, can we reuse that connection any how?

Comment: No, it won't. [Comment need more characters...]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's opened with `fsockopen()`, it will be closed when the script finishes. If you want the socket to persist between script executions, check out [`pfsockopen()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pfsockopen.php), which is provided exactly for this usecase.